# How to give corner radius using storyboard?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, storyboard, uitextfield

i want to give brder radious like

key path : layer.cormerRadios
value : frame.size.height / 2

in story board there is an one more option type so which type should i give ?

Comment: kindly provide an example to understand

Comment: iwhen we give corner radious programatically we do myTextField.layer.cornerRadious = myTextField.frame.size.height / 2 ---------- how can i achive using stry board i dont want to give specific height

Comment: Maybe a spelling problem? cor**m**erRadi**o**s vs cor**n**erRadi**u**s ?

Comment: spelling is correct but i want to do it in storyboard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

easiest way is to create an @IBInspectable as an extension

```
extension UIView {

@IBInspectable
    var cornerRadius: CGFloat {
        get {
            return layer.cornerRadius
        }
        set {
            layer.cornerRadius = newValue
        }
    }

}
```

[Corner Radius in IB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yz97V.png)

Comment: i want to do using storyboard

Comment: when you mark it as an @IBInspectable it shows up in IB. i have added a screenshot to my answer.